# systemd service unit Restart=on-failure doesn't restart daemon

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I want to write a service unit file that'll start a daemon and restart it if it dies. I have:

```
[Unit]
Description=lmgrd

[Service]
User=flexlm
Group=flexlm
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/cp /nfs/lmgrd/* /lm/
ExecStart=/lm/lmgrd -c /lm/license.lic -l /lm/lmgrd.log
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
RemainAfterExit=yes
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This copies the files and starts the daemon, but if I kill the daemon (lmgrd), it doesn't get restarted. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it doesn't get restarted because systemd thinks the service **did not have** a daemon running in the first place. If you look at `systemctl status` while the daemon is still there, you'll probably see "Status: active (exited)" and no Main PID listed.

By default, FlexLM lmgrd will *fork* (daemonize) on startup; the initial process exits almost immediately, while the child process is the "main" daemon process that needs to be tracked.

The problem is that systemd hasn't been told about this – without a Type= setting in the service, the default is actually Type=simple which tells systemd to track the *initial* process instead. Therefore, as soon as lmgrd daemonizes, systemd thinks that the "main" process has exited and would normally report the service as stopped.

In your case, systemd still *pretends* that the service is still "active" because RemainAfterExit=yes has been set, but isn't actually tracking any process anymore; the lmgrd process that's still running is only considered to be a leftover child/worker process and its exit doesn't influence the service status anymore.

To fix this, **remove the `RemainAfterExit=` option** and **add the `Type=forking` option.** The latter is the correct way to handle a service that will "daemonize" or "fork into background". (Systemd will automatically determine the main process without the need for "PID files".)

Alternatively, you could stay with Type=simple (but still remove RemainAfterExit!) but instead configure the process to *not* daemonize – FlexLM has the `-z` option to "run in foreground".

(Type=simple is often recommended but is not always the strictly better choice; Type=forking also has the advantage of informing systemd *when* the service is ready, which often outweighs the "simplicity" advantage of Type=simple. Though this only matters if the daemon times its 'daemonization' correctly – lmgrd doesn't – and if the system has any services configured to depend on this one – which there probably aren't in this case, either, so `-z` is okay to use.)

For a general rule of thumb, never use RemainAfterExit=yes unless the ExecStart in question is *expected* to exit (most of the time you'd also use Type=oneshot for such services). For example, nftables.service may use this option because the firewall ruleset stays loaded even after the `nft` process has exited. For long-lived daemons, however, the only effect of RemainAfterExit=yes is negative – it makes systemd ignore failures.

---

As an additional note, systemd **does not** expand wildcards in ExecStart (the commands are run without using a shell, so none of the usual shell operators will work). The command will be trying to copy a file literally named `*`.

You should change it either to copy the directory's contents recursively:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/cp -rv /nfs/lmgrd/. /lm/
```

or to run a shell for the wildcard expansion:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "cp -v /nfs/lmgrd/* /lm/"
```

Comment: On the other hand, on-failure might not work when the process is manually killed? (Since the exit code might be "clean")

Comment: @user1686 that was a great answer. Thank you. Adding `-z` to `lmgrd` and making the Type=simple worked for me. Notably though, after killing lmgrd, it took 1.5m to respawn even when I set RestartSec=3. Using `systemctl stop lmgrd` also took about a minute to finish executing even though the daemon died immediately. Those are acceptable waits in my case. `systemctl status` looked reasonable in all cases. I also tried using Type=forking and without `-z`, but I had difficulty running systemctl stop then start. I removed `RemainAfterExit=` in all cases.

Comment: Does it work better if you have `ExecStop=/lm/lmutil lmdown`? Does the cgroup (shown in 'systemctl status lmgrd') have any other processes when it's "stopped"? It sounds like the vendor daemon is not exiting when it should, so systemd is waiting for the timeout before issuing the SIGKILL.